# Flask session data does not persist between sessions

Tags: python, reactjs, api, flask

I am building this website using React and Python with Flask. The session data gets lost between session and I don't know why.

This is the app configuration in Python, in app.py file:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = secrets.token_hex(16)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:root@localhost/agentie_imobiliara'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE'] = False
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(days=7)
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY'] = True
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE'] = "None"
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_NAME'] = 'session'
CORS(app, origins='*', supports_credentials=True)
Session(app)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And these are the login() and get_user_role() functions, in Routes.py file:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    try:
        email = request.json['email']
        password = request.json['password']
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

        if user and user.password == password:
            session['user_id'] = user.id
            session['user_email'] = user.email
            session['user_role'] = user.role
            session.modified = True
            session.permanent = True
            return jsonify({'message': 'Login successful', 'user_id': user.id,
                            'user_email': user.email, 'user_role': user.role})
        else:
            return jsonify({'message': 'Invalid email or password'})
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return jsonify({'message': 'An error occurred'})


@app.route('/user_role', methods=['GET'])
def get_user_role():
    print(f"Session contents: {session}")
    if 'user_role' in session:
        user_role = session.get('user_role')
        return jsonify({'user_role': user_role})
    else:
        return jsonify({'message': 'User not logged in'})
```

This is the React code where I fetch the login API:

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        try {
            const response = await axios.post(
                "http://127.0.0.1:5000/login",

                { email: email, password: password },
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    },
                }
            );
                alert(response.data.message);
            if (response.status === 200 && response.data.message === "Login successful") {
                onLoginSuccess(true);
                setIsLoggedIn(true);
                history.push('/');
                console.log("isLoggedIn:", isLoggedIn);
                console.log("onLoginSuccess:", onLoginSuccess);

            }
        } catch (error) {
            alert("Invalid email or password");
        }
    };
```

and here I fetch the get_user_role API:

```
useEffect(() => {
        // Fetch the user's role from the API
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/user_role', { credentials: 'include' })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setRole(data.role))
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }, []);
```

I tried to put different print statments in the backend code to print the session contents and it gets empty between the requests. I need the get_user_role to render different pages based on the role. I don't know where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

the `withCredentials` attribute have to be set to `true`  in your `axios` `POST` request for the `login` API.

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(
            "http://127.0.0.1:5000/login",
            { email: email, password: password },
            {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                withCredentials: true, // Add this line
            }
        );
        alert(response.data.message);
        if (response.status === 200 && response.data.message === "Login successful") {
            onLoginSuccess(true);
            setIsLoggedIn(true);
            history.push('/');
            console.log("isLoggedIn:", isLoggedIn);
            console.log("onLoginSuccess:", onLoginSuccess);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        alert("Invalid email or password");
    }
};
```

Comment: i added what you sugested and the session data still gets lost between the requests.